# If $T_{1}$ is dominated by $T_{2}$ and $T_{2}$ is a compact operator, can we deduce that $T_{1}$ is a compact operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compact-operators

Suppose $T_{1},T_{2}$ are two bounded linear operators from $L^{2}(\mathbb{R^{n}})$ to $L^{2}(\mathbb{R^{n}})$. In addition, for any $f,g\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R^{n}})$ and $x\in \mathbb{R^{n}}$, $$|T_{1}(f)(x)|\leq T_{2}(|f|)(x) \quad and \quad T_{2}(|f+g|)(x)\leq T_{2}(|f|)(x)+T_{2}(|g|)(x).$$ If $T_{2}$ is a compact operator from $L^{2}(\mathbb{R^{n}})$ to $L^{2}(\mathbb{R^{n}})$, can we deduce that $T_{1}$ is a compact operator from $L^{2}(\mathbb{R^{n}})$ to $L^{2}(\mathbb{R^{n}})$?

Actually, in the article "Sparse domination results for compactness on weighted spaces", the authors used this technique to show that some Calderón-Zygmund operators have compact extensions on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R^{n}})$, but they did not explain how to get the compactness of Calderón-Zygmund operators in their article. You can find this article on https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10290

Comment: Your second inequality actually follows from the first one, as the first inequality implies that the operator $T$ is positive (in the sense of Banach lattice theory). Anyway, the answer to your question is "yes": compactness is inherited under domination on reflexive Banach lattices. You can find this, for instance, in the book "Banach lattices" by Meyer-Nieberg (1991).

Comment: @Jochen Glueck If $T_{1}, T_{2}$ are positive linear operators, we can use Theorem 3.7.13 (in the book "Banach lattices"). But here $T_{1}, T_{2}$ are not positive operators. If we define a new operator $T_{3}(f):=T_{2}(|f|)$, $T_{3}$ is a positive operator, but $T_{3}$ may not be a linear operator.

Comment: Yes, Theorem 3.7.13 is only stated for positive operators, but one can easily get it under the weaker domination assumption $|T_1 f| \leq T_2|f|$ (where $T_1$ does not need to be positive): Due to the domination assumption, $T_1$ is order bounded, and as every reflexive Banach lattice is Dedekind complete, you can apply Theorem 1.3.2 in [op. cit.] to decompose $T_1$ as $T_1 = T_1^+ - T_1^-$. The operators $T_1^+$ and $T_1^-$ are both positive and dominated by $T_2$, so they are compact by Theorem 3.7.13. Hence, $T_1$ is compact.

Comment: By the way, as I said in my first comment (with a typo, though), $T_2$ is automatically a positive operator due to your first assumption: for $f \ge 0$ you have $T_2f = T_2|f| \ge |T_1 f| \ge 0$, so $T_2$ is positive.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. Under which assumptions compactness of operators is inherited under domination is an important question in operator theory on Banach lattices. It's also a very natural question to ask (even if one doesn't have any concrete application in mind), so I'm not sure which kind of context is puportedly lacking in the question.

Comment: @Jochen Glueck I have added the context of this question. If $T_{1}$ is a special sublinear operator that satisfies $T_{1}(f)\geq 0 $ for any $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R^{n}})$, can we still get the compactness of $T_{1}$?

Comment: My knowledge about the non-linear case is, unfortunately, subpar (to put it mildly). My only idea at first glance would be to try to immitate the proof of the linear case (but I have not thought about it, so I don't know whether it might work).